# c# add parameter for each methods in class

Tags: c#

```
public class BaseDAL
{
    protected object GetOrder(int id)
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public object GetByID(int id)
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any option to add this param `int id`
for any function in class without write it each function?

Somthing like:

```
public class BaseDAL : ADD SOME CODE THAT SHARE int id for all funcs
{
    protected object GetOrder()
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public object GetByID()
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

and `GetOrder(12);` will works.
I want this done only to reduce the code.

Comment: You want a function that takes a parameter, but you don't want to include that parameter in the code? The compiler is at this time unable to read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could set an ID parameter in the constructor, like so:

```
public class BaseDAL
{

    public BaseDAL(int ID)
    {
       this.id= ID;
    }

    int id;

    protected object GetOrder()
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public object GetByID()
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

That allows you to write code like this:

```
var result = new BaseDAL(5).GetOrder();
```

You could also combine this with the other answer, so that you have a property you can set and change. But I don't really think either is a good idea. I think what you already have is better. Also, I think you'd be better served to return `Order` and `Video` objects, rather than `Object`s.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `CurrentIndex` property to your class

```
public class BaseDAL
{
    public CurrentIndex { get; set; }

    public Order GetOrder()
    {
        using (var DB = AccessManager.db) {
            return DB.Videos.Where(x => x.ID == CurrentIndex).SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and use it like this

```
var dal = new BaseDAL();
dal.CurrentIndex = 5;
var result = dal.GetOrder();
```

Comment: Somthing like this but call the function like:                   var dal = new BaseDAL();
var result = dal.GetOrder(5);

Comment: No. If you want to call a method with parameters, you have to define them at the method declaration! What's wrong with declaring the parameter at each method declaration? `int id` has 6 characters, could it be that you are a bit lazy?